# Emberjs bindAttr id-prefix

Tags: ember.js

I am loading multiple models (using an ArrayController) with ember-data that obviously returns and id for each model and I am displaying some dynamic map content based on that, which is initialized via JS in the `didInsertElement` function.
So my hbs code looks like this:

```
{{#each controller}}
    ....
    <div class="map" {{bindAttr id="id"}}>
    ....
{{/each}}
```

That works fine, but my problem is, I don't just want the id-number for the div id, but I want it with a static prefix: E.g. `user-{{id}}`. Or at a different route I would want e.g. `news-{{id}}`
Is anything like that possible?

Comment: do you have in your models you are looping over the prefixes you need?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can store the prefix in you model data, you could create a computed property for this use case:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  prefixedId: function() {
    return "user-" + this.get('id');
  }.property('id')
});

App.News = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  prefixedId: function() {
    return "news-" + this.get('id');
  }.property('id')
});
```

And then use the computed property instead:

```
{{#each controller}}
  ....
  <div class="map" {{bindAttr id="prefixedId"}}>
  ....
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hmm... I haven't thought about that, but that unfortunately won't completely my issue, because 2 of the routes are sub-routes, so they use the same model just with a parameter added. I was trying to do something similar in the Controller. But I am really having trouble working with the ArrayController and getting 'access' to each individual ID. Do you think there is another way? In any case, thank you for bringing that up. That is really appreciated.

Comment: The ArrayController will not give you access to the individual ids, it's just a wrapper around the array. What you want is to specify an `itemController` that will be used to wrap each item in the array. You can do that by specifying an `itemController` property either on your ArrayController or as a parameter to the handlebars `{{each}}` helper. Array Controller API docs has a pretty good explanation of all this, see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Comment: Thank you Mike, that seems exactly what I need. Will update it as soon as I get the time to implement it.